# How to determine which variables are the best predictor of an outcome?

Tags: logistic, feature-selection

I have a series of health parameters e.g. heart rate, age, blood pressure, blood glucose level of >1000 patients with heart disease. I want to determine which parameters can predict the likelihood of an individual suffering from heart disease. Once I determine the best combination of these parameters, I can use this formula to calculate how likely a person will suffer from the heart disease.

May I know which method I should use? And is there any simple and free software that can do the job?

Comment: How do you measure heart disease?

Comment: Why are you interested in identifying predictors? Why would you not use all predictors and then let a prediction model find the best fit?

Comment: To begin with, a quick and easy trick is to plot a "heatmap" for correlation, which helps you to select visually the best predictors. Perhaps this link can help: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-quick-correlation-matrix-heatmap-r-software-and-data-visualization